# how to append output to a CSV file

Tags: powershell, sccm

```
foreach ( $newfile in $file ) 
{ 
   $b =  Get-CMDeploymentStatus -PackageId $newfile -StatusType Any | select PackageID
 Write-Output $b | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\PSM-6A1A000000000000\Documents\list.csv"
}
```

I am giving input to this with an input file which has number of package names listed and then I want to process it in such a way that the output comes one after the other right now I am getting an error as

Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null. At line:16 char:20 + Write-Output $b | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\PSM-6A1A000000000000\Documents\lis ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidData: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingValidationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand

Comment: It is really hard to read your question and it looks like your problem is not reproducible, because we are missing `$file`. Please format every code snippet as code and provide a minimal working example that will produce your error. [Read more about how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is assuming that you will have a result coming back from `$b`, if it does not though, you'll get an error because you're piping `$b`, which is null, into `Export-CSV`.

```
$null |export-csv c:\temp\1.csv
Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At line:1 char:8
+ $null |export-csv c:\temp\1.csv
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCs
```

You should add a 'Guard Clause' before you try to export.

```
if ($null -ne $b){
   Export-csv -Append -InputObject $b
}
```

At least this will continue executing.  Now your next problem is to determine why `$b` would be empty...from my experience with CM, I bet you need to specify which property in your `$file` you need.  Maybe that line should read:

`$b =  Get-CMDeploymentStatus -PackageId $newfile.PackageId -StatusType Any | select PackageID`

Answer (score 0):

Since you say *"I am giving input to this with an input file which has number of package **names** listed"*, but your code uses `PackageId`..

It looks to me that this file contains a packageId, each on a single line.

Anyway, I don't see the code ever reading this file..

If my assumption about the text file is correct, try:

```
# read the content of the text file and loop through the lines
# collect the output from Get-CMDeploymentStatus in variable $result
$result = Get-Content -Path 'X:\TheFileWithPackageIds.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    # inside the ForEach-Object, the $_ automatic variable represents a single line from the text file
    Get-CMDeploymentStatus -PackageId $_ -StatusType Any | select PackageID
}

# output on screen
$result

# write to new CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\PSM-6A1A000000000000\Documents\list.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```